# How PLINQ is better than traditional threading?

Tags: multithreading, plinq

Currently I have n suppliers web service which gives me search result for particular product. I am creating n threads myself and merging the final results returned by supplier. I have just come to know about PLINQ. I want to know if it would help the performance. If yes, how.

Answer (score 2):

Better? Depends on what that means for you. PLINQ is definitely cleaner and more maintainable code for a lot of use cases. On the performance side depends on what you compare it against.

In your case if you are creating n threads by hand i would say you **might** be slower because PLINQ will use the threadpool and avoid some thread creation overhead.